# How to know there is a maintenance job running on a postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, maintenance, vacuum

I have a python script on postgresql database which is fetching records from sql server database and inserting it to postgresql DB after some filtering. this jobs is running by `cron` every two minutes. I want to know when there is maintenance job such as `autovacuum` is running and if running forget fetching records. Is it possible to detect in python?

Comment: Don't bother. There is no problem inserting into the table at the same time as vacuum is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In current versions of PostgreSQL, you can look at the *pg_stat_activity* view to find autovacuum tasks.  They will have *current_query* fields that start with "Mark autovacuum entries in pg_stat_activity that look like this:

```
autovacuum: VACUUM t
```

A query to count how many of those you have might look like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE position('autovacuum:' IN current_query) = 1;
```

And you can have your Python code check if the value returned is >0; if so, autovacuum is running.  You might want to track down and avoid running concurrently with manual VACUUM calls, too.